# How to detect the Here SDK map small pans and ignore them

Tags: android, dictionary, sdk, here-api

We have Here SDK `MapFragment` in our app and since it is possible that user single taps on map interpret as pan event I am trying to ignore small pan movements and recenter the map.

My first issue is that the `MapGesture.OnGestureListener`'s `onPanStart()` and `onPanEnd()` events don't give any information about amount of pan (how much the user finger traveled on screen).

Then I start saving map center `onPanStart()` and get the distance with the map center at `onPanEnd()` but since the map is tilted and sometimes zoomed I don't get a fix distance by finger movements.

```
    val distance = lastCenter.distanceTo(mapFragment.map.center)
    if (distance < 80) recenter()
```

Any solution or better idea to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Camera returned by mapView.getCamera() to manipulate the view of the map.Convert between view and geographical coordinate spaces by using geoToViewCoordinates() and viewToGeoCoordinates().

```
private void setLongPressGestureHandler(MapViewLite mapView) {
    mapView.getGestures().setLongPressListener(new LongPressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLongPress(@NonNull GestureState gestureState, @NonNull Point2D touchPoint) {
            GeoCoordinates geoCoordinates = mapView.getCamera().viewToGeoCoordinates(touchPoint);

            if (gestureState == GestureState.BEGIN) {
                Log.d(TAG, "LongPress detected at: " + geoCoordinates);
            }

            if (gestureState == GestureState.UPDATE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "LongPress update at: " + geoCoordinates);
            }

            if (gestureState == GestureState.END) {
                Log.d(TAG, "LongPress finger lifted at: " + geoCoordinates);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is `MapViewLite`? I don't have it in Here Android SDK. I only have access to `mapGesture` and `map` using `AndroidXMapFragment`.
Plus I am talking about taps and pans this code is about LongPress.